# Stripe + webtask.io doesn't work after upgrade to Node 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using webtask.io to create a Stripe charge based on Thomasz` example [here](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2016/01/accept-stripe-payments-without-backend-using-webtasks.html) but after they upgraded from Node 4 to Node 8 this doesn't work anymore. Any idea of how to make this work again?

```
var stripe = require('stripe');

module.exports = function (ctx, req, res) {
    stripe(ctx.secrets.stripeSecretKey).charges.create({
        amount: ctx.body.amount * 100,
        currency: 'gbp',
        source: ctx.body.stripeToken,
        description: 'Test Payment',
    }, function (error, charge) {
        var status = error ? 400 : 200;
        var message = error ? error.message : '<script>window.location.replace("' + ctx.body.redirectUrl + '");</script>'; 
        res.writeHead(status, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        return res.end('<h1>' + message + '</h1>');
    });
};
```

Error:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "error": "Script generated an unhandled synchronous exception.",
    "details": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined",
    "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined\n    at module.exports (/data/io/ea441d92-6f8c-46b0-a9a9-6c8098f03aac/webtask.js:5:26)\n    at Async.waterfall (/data/sandbox/lib/sandbox.js:519:33)\n    at nextTask (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)\n    at next (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5331:9)\n    at /data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16\n    at Async.waterfall (/data/sandbox/lib/sandbox.js:408:24)\n    at nextTask (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)\n    at next (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5331:9)\n    at /data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)"
}
```

Comment: LE: `amount` is user defined and sent via the form.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no `amount` property in the request body that Stripe Checkout is sending to the webtask. This is by design- the `data-amount` property only affects the amount that is *shown* to the user. The reason for this is that you should not use a value from the frontend to decide the amount of the charge. It would be trivial for me to open my browser devtools and change the amount, and now instead of paying $9.99 for your product, I'm paying $1 :)

To workaround this, you have two options:

- Set the `amount` argument of `stripe.charges.create` in your backend webtask to a value directly. This is the recommended approach if you are trying to charge the customer a specific amount.
- Use a hidden input on your form as shown below. Note that this has the issue I described above where the user could change the value. This is not necessarily a problem in a 'donation' use case(like the example you linked to), since you want the user to choose the amount anyway(in which case just use a normal, non-hidden input instead).

Hidden input:

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="999">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="API_KEY"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Test"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="usd">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I should have mentioned that `amount` is also sent via the form (there are workarounds for this) because I'm using this to allow users to pay a user configurable amount... I tried setting a fixed value for amount but then I'm getting the same error but for `ctx.body.stripeToken`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

If you're using `Full HTTP control` (context, req, res) the body of the request will be unconsumed unless the `pb` claim of the webtask token is set to 1.

To do so you need to create your script using:

```
wt create my-script.js --secret stripeSecretKey={stripe_api_key} --parse-body --dependency stripe@3.3.4 --ignore-package-json
```

Comment: I am having difficulty solving the issue by installing parse-body through Webtask's console. "stripeToken" is still undefined. Can you give some pointers? I am defining stripeToken through "var token = req.body.stripeToken;" Thanks!